# How to set the format on a WinForms ComboBox AutoComplete drop down

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, autocomplete, format

I'm using a Winforms ComboBox, specifying the background color and font programatically.  I've also set AutoCompleteMode to "Suggest" and AutoCompleSource to "ListItems", via the designer properties.

Autocomplete seems to work great, but the drop down it displays for auto complete uses the Winforms default background color and font.  I'd like it to match the background color and font of the rest of the control.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this in .Net 4.0?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot do this.  Setting the background colour only affects the "TextBox" part of a ComboBox, i.e. when you are using a ComboBox in DropDown style (default) allowing the user to enter free text as well as selecting from the list.